# Insert file into azure container

Tags: .net, azure, asp.net-core

I have this code that works fine, however I need now for .net core, it does not work:

```
public class StorageAzure
{
    private CloudStorageAccount storageAccount;
    private CloudBlobContainer containerPadrao;
    public StorageAzure()
    {
        this.storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
            CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));

        this.containerPadrao = inicializarContainer();
    }

    private List<CloudBlobContainer> ListaContainers()
    {
        CloudBlobClient blobCLient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        return blobCLient.ListContainers().ToList();
    }

    private CloudBlobContainer getContainer(string NomeContainer)
    {
        CloudBlobClient blobCLient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        return blobCLient.ListContainers().ToList().Where(c => c.Name == NomeContainer).FirstOrDefault();
    }

    private CloudBlobContainer inicializarContainer()
    {
        return getContainer(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["containerpadrao"]);
    }

    public void AdicionarArquivo(string caminho, string nome)
    {
        CloudBlockBlob blob = containerPadrao.GetBlockBlobReference(nome);

        blob.UploadFromFile(caminho, FileMode.Open);
    }
}
```

How can I list the containers in .net core ?
He can't find ListContainers, I found some examples, but none I could make it work.
**EDIT**

In .netcore does not have the same libraries, so I don't know which libraries to use to be able to list a container, and also send a file.

Comment: Please describe "it does not work"

Comment: @CSharpRocks sorry, I edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are just looking for .net core code to upload blobs and list containers, just try this .net core console app below:

```
using Azure.Storage.Blobs;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace blobUpload
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string localFilePath = "<path of file to upload>";
            string containerName = "<container name>";
            string storageConnStr = "<storage account connection string>";


            BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(storageConnStr);
            Console.WriteLine("====listContainers====");
            listContainers(blobServiceClient);

            Console.WriteLine("====listContainerBlobs====");
            listContainerBlobs(blobServiceClient, containerName);

            Console.WriteLine("====upload files to a Container====");
            uploadFiles(blobServiceClient, localFilePath, containerName);


        }

        public static void uploadFiles(BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient,String filePath,string containerName) {
            var container = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName);
            var blobClient = container.GetBlobClient("testFile.zip");
            Console.WriteLine(blobClient.UploadAsync(filePath).GetAwaiter().GetResult());
        }

        public static void listContainers(BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient) {
            var containerEmulator = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainers().GetEnumerator();
            
            while (containerEmulator.MoveNext()) {
                Console.WriteLine(containerEmulator.Current.Name);
            }
        }

        public static void listContainerBlobs(BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient,string containerName)
        {
            var container = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName);
            var blobEmulator = container.GetBlobs().GetEnumerator();
            while (blobEmulator.MoveNext())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(blobEmulator.Current.Name);
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Result :
[image]
the uploaded file:
[image]

Comment: How do I get the appsettings.json setup? I tried this way and couldn't.
`var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");
            IConfigurationRoot configuration = builder.Build();
            string connectionString = configuration.GetSection("AzureStorageConfigVO").ToString();`

Comment: Hi @Mari, if you are developing asp.net core web app, just refer to this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#appsettingsjson . Btw,  this question has nothing to do with your first question. If your first question has been solved, please click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in ot mark my post as an answer to close this question. If you have other questions, please post a new one. On stackoverflow, it's one question one post.